# Java write record or message to log file problem

Tags: java, logging

```
try {
    // Create an appending file handler
    boolean append = true;
    FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("my.log", append);

    // Add to the desired logger
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.mycompany");
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "This is info message");
    logger.addHandler(handler);
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

My problem is when i open my.log file i don't see the text "This is info message" but just

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
<log>
</log>
```

Can anyone point me out where is problem???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should add handler before you log something.

Comment: Thank you! You are right i tried adding handler before logging and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the appender before logging anything is logged

```
try {
    // Create an appending file handler
    boolean append = true;
    FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("my.log", append);

    // Add to the desired logger
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.mycompany");
    logger.addHandler(handler);

    logger.log(Level.INFO, "This is info message");
    } catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the docs:

> Each Logger has a "Level" associated with it.

Maybe the level configured for this logger is too high for INFO level messages to show up.